# ionice equivalent for MacOS?

Tags: macos, backup, multitasking

On Linux systems I use [ionice](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html) to lower I/O scheduling priority for processes like backups that interfere as little as possible with interactive usage of the system. Is there an equivalent for MacOS?

Comment: I find nice and renice do that.

Answer (score 6):

On macOS you'll find a similar program named `taskpolicy` that comes with the system. It allows you to both start a new program with a specific I/O scheduling policy, as well as change the I/O scheduling policy for an already running process. You will want to run it with the `-d` parameter, allowing you to set the I/O policy as either `important` (highest priority), `standard`, `utility` or `throttle` (lowest priority). There's also a level named `passive` that basically ignores priorities all together.

A simpler, open-source alternative also exists here:

https://github.com/DrHyde/ionice-MacOS

It allows you to set the I/O scheduling priority for a new command you start, but you cannot change it for an already running process or query an already running process for its priority.